# Optimization vs Optimisation in tags

Tags: discussion, tags

It took longer than I expected, but the first [tag](https://or.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/experimental-optimisation) spelling optimization as optimisation has been introduced.

I know this is an american-english versus british-english debate.

However, google gives about 10x as many results for optimization than optimisation, and I think tags should generally use the more common option.

Opinions?

Comment: SE veterans: Is there a system-wide preference as to standardizing to American vs. British English vs. letting everyone use whichever idiom they prefer?

Comment: there are discussions on various stackexchanges, e.g. [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/23869/what-should-the-standard-spelling-be-british-or-us), and [here](https://photo.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/146/british-english-vs-american-english-in-tags)

Comment: Seems the general consensus on those two threads is, use US English for tags, use whatever you like for everything else.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

By convention tags should be in American spelling. So [optimization](https://or.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/optimization) is default, but you can add the synonym [optimisation](https://or.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/optimisation)

See this page on the main Meta.SE: [What should the standard spelling be - British or US?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/23869/what-should-the-standard-spelling-be-british-or-us?noredirect=1&lq=1)

I quote (by [Shog9](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/811/shog9)):

> > Does SOFU have an accepted standard on language and spelling? Which is it?
>
> For bodies, no. **For tags, US-English.**

Answer (score 9):

I'd vote to follow Google and the consensus elsewhere (i.e., US for tags; free-for-all elsewhere).

An open question is queueing vs. queuing though :) Perhaps we can let the first asker decide.

Comment: I think queueing :)

Comment: Queuing all the way!

Answer (score 3):

If I am not wrong, in the UK (also Australia afaik) OR is called Operation**al** Research. So I guess if the community is named as Operations Research, we should follow American English, right?